# Search and Immediately get the results after creating new items in lists or libraries

Tags: search-results, fast-search

I have a sharepoint site. I want my users create new items in libraries and lists and when we search for them, they appear immediately in results. Is it ok to create scheduled incremental crawl every 1 minutes? Is that hurts my bandwidth? What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to search specific information from a single site collection throgh a special UI then you may be able to use [SharePoint 2010 Site Search](http://sitesearch.codeplex.com/) which translates the search into CAML queries.

Usually you'll setup the servers doing the crawl to request information from themselves so it'll "only" hurt that/these server(s) and SQL.

But every minute is probably not possible.

In SharePoint 2013 they introduce continuous crawling, which will solve the problem.

Comment: +1 for the SP2013 info

Comment: Continuous crawling will not solve this. Continuous crawling is merely a substitute for creating an incremental crawl schedule as it will adapt to how frequent the content changes. Default it will start on a 15 minute interval.

Comment: The change is that at least for "medium Internet sites topology" MS recommends that you change that to every minute ([Scale search for performance and availability in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219628(v=office.15).aspx))

Answer (score 0):

You may perform an incremental crawl frequently, but every 1 minute is not recommended. Go through this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262794%28office.12%29.aspx) consider everything and determine the most accurate frequency.